# Как создать ячейки table программно используя thymeleaf?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <p th:utext="${user_id}">
  </th>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${active}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${email}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${last_name}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${name}">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <p th:utext="${user_id2}">
  </th>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${active2}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${email2}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${last_name2}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${name2}">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <p th:utext="${user_id3}">
  </th>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${active3}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${email3}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${last_name3}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${name3}">
  </td>
</tr>0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать [цикл](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration)

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
  <th scope="row">
    <p th:utext="${user.id}">
  </th>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${user.active}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${user.email}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${user.last_name}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <p th:utext="${user.name}">
  </td>
</tr>
```